# Qt array of char pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers

I am trying to store the value of a hexadecimal in a character pointer array and pass it to another function, which computes the CRC of the hexadecimal values.  But the issue is that some times the output is the same or at some times the value of pttr[0] is 0.

This is result which I am getting now, 0xFF 0xFF. Is there something I am doing wrong here ? Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    char *pttr[2];
    pttr[0] =  QString("0x%1").arg(155, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0')).toLatin1().data();
    pttr[1] =  QString("0x%1").arg(255, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0')).toLatin1().data();

    printf("%s \n",pttr[0]);
    printf("%s \n",pttr[1]);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using

```
char *pttr[2];
pttr[0] =  QString("0x%1").arg(155, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0')).toLatin1().data();
pttr[1] =  QString("0x%1").arg(255, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0')).toLatin1().data();
```

is that there are two levels of temporary objects.

`QString("0x%1").arg(155, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0'))` creates a temporary `QString` object.
`QString("0x%1").arg(155, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0')).toLatin1()` creates a temporary `QByteArray` object.

After those lines are finished executing, `pttr` ends up holding two dangling pointers. Dereferencing those pointers causes undefined behavior.

Please note that even

```
QString str("Some value");
char const* cp = str.toLatin1().constData();
```

is not correct. `cp` is a dangling pointer in this case also.

You should hold on to the `QString` objects and use `toLatin1().constData()` when you need to get read-only access to the underlying `char` objects.

```
QString str_array[2];
str_array[0] =  QString("0x%1").arg(155, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0'));
str_array[1] =  QString("0x%1").arg(255, 2, 16, QLatin1Char('0'));

printf("%s \n", str_array[0].toLatin1().constData());
printf("%s \n", str_array[1].toLatin1().constData());
```

Comment: ..or just operate directly on QByteArray, which avoids the unnecessary toLatin1() conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The array returned by `data` is still owned by the `QString`. If you have a temporary `QString` like that, it'll be destroyed at the end of the statement, leaving the returned pointer pointing to uninitialized memory.

In general you should keep your strings in `QString`s when using Qt. If you need to get a `char*` out of one, do it at the moment of need, not to initialize a `char*` variable.